# How to solve "The node '...' was not found." in SVN

Tags: svn, version-control

I've merged two branches (trunk and a development branch). A folder has dissapeared.

I'm working in command line and when trying to say `svn resolve --accept working src/path/to/folder` the terminal spits out `The node 'src/path/to/folder' was not found`

After that it also spits out:

`svn: E200009: Could not add all targets because some targets don't exist`

`svn: E200009: Illegal target for the requested operation`

How can I force SVN to accept this change?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I was hitting this error trying to use TortoiseSVN to update a working copy. In my case I managed to workaround by using the SVN commandline interface instead to `svn update`. Even after a successful commit I was still unable to update.

Very odd but a manual delete and update seemed to clean everything up. Both of my clients were based on Subversion 1.7.6.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I won't be able to test this out though as this problem happened a long time ago, and I can't replicate it at the moment.

Comment: Indeed quite weird. I did the manual delete and updated and it corrected my problem as well.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like some info is broken. Which seems to happen during merge with tree conflicts.

I had to fix the svn database which is the file **.svn/wc.db**.

WARNING! You are manipulating the svn database which can be harmful! Do this only if you have a backup and if this procedure does not help, restore the data from backup.

1. Go to SQLite from [SQLite Download Page](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html), download the archive of the precompiled binary for your platform and extract it e.g. to **/tools**
2. Change into the **.svn** directory make a backup of the **wv.db** (!) and run **sqlite3** with **wc.db** as parameter. E.g.

   `\tools\sqlite3.exe wc.db`
3. Search the entries causing the problem with

   `select * from actual_node where conflict_data like '%missing%';`

   or

   `select * from actual_node where conflict_data like '%obstructed%';`

   refine these queries until only the faulty actual nodes are listed. Also

   `select * from actual_node where local_relpath like '%...%';`

   is helpful to find the faulty nodes.
4. Remove the faulty nodes by replacing the **select** with a **delete**

   `delete from actual_node where conflict_data like '%missing%';`
5. Check again with your favorite svn tool.
6. Rinse and repeat until all problems are gone.

WARNING! You are manipulating the svn database which can be harmful! Do this only if you have a backup and if this procedure does not help, restore the data from backup.

For me it worked several times.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem occur due to the working copy being checked out using the DNS name of the server, e.g. http://myServer/svn/software/Trunk/ ; and the branch from which I was telling my SVN client to merge was the same branch, only being referenced directly by its IP address, e.g. http://10.140.1.29/svn/software/Branches/myBranch/ . Very easy to overlook when using a GUI-based client such as TortoiseSVN, and the cryptic error messages such as "node not found" don't really tell you anything. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I had the same problem, but with two different DNS names for the same SVN server. The problem disappeared when I used the same DNS name for the working copy and the merged branch.

Answer (score 0):

Had this too in Eclipse. I did several refresh, svn cleanup, etc but nothing helped.

Then I did SVN commit from the command line which worked fine.

Comment: you can write it as comment too. This not seems like answer.

Answer (score 0):

For me I was using the "Test Merge" button in Tortoise SVN and I was getting this error. Eventually I just clicked "Merge" for real and the error didn't show...

Answer (score -1):

I deleted the file's folder and updated it again. I found that doing this resolved this problem.

Comment: Deleting the folder and then doing SVN update gives update failed. it first restores that deleted folder and then complains it is not found on server